# TypeError at /signup object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, django

**My view:**

```
class RegistrationView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

    def post(self, request):
        context={
            'data':request.POST,
            'has_error':False
        }
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        username = request.POST.get('username')

        if len(password)<8:
            messages.add_message(request,messages.ERROR, 'Password should be atleast 8 characters long !!!')
            context['has_error']=True
```

Comment: If you can put additional information on your question, we can surely get answer or perhaps number of it. The "TypeError at /signup object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" is vague.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Check out the names in the form input fields they are **case sensitive** In django it is `Password` and not `password` and same for other fields.

Then pass the **default value `''`** in case it is not found to **avoid None**.

Else explicitly check **it is not None** before using `len()`.

```
 username = request.POST.get('Username', '')
 password = request.POST.get('Password', '')
```